# New Google maps parameters

Tags: google-maps

Does anyone have a good reference for the new google maps parameters.  It seems maps are now in the format

```
https://www.google.com/maps/@40.07304,-74.724323,8z
```

Where the first two parameters are the LAT and LONG, the third is the zoom level.  Are there other parameters to customize such as a marker location.

Comment: there has never been a "reference" for these parameters(no matter if old or new maps), there is no related API

Answer (score 1):

Could not find any official documentation from Google, but the Moz Blog has a description on the [new Google Maps URL structure](http://moz.com/blog/new-google-maps-url-parameters).

If you want to integrate with Google Maps (instead of just providing a link to a map), Google Maps has a couple of [web APIs for maps](https://developers.google.com/maps/web/):

- [Google Maps Javascript API](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/tutorial)
- [Google Maps Embed API](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/embed/guide)
- [Google Maps Image APIs](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/staticmaps/)

Those pages do describe the location format (and the API Key to be used).